# Mysql - show results from 3 tables excluding NULL or EMPTY values for certain fields

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, php, query-performance

I have 3 simple tables with `polls`, `users` and `votes`. I'd like to show all polls ordered by clean count of votes (sometimes either `poll_id` or `user_id` don't get inserted).

Furthermore I'd like to show a list of users voted, similar to fb (for now my solution is to get that list with new query fetched by ajax call.)

would it be better to create one query to get all results and read them separatelly from array or is it best practice to create separate requests?

My query bellow does get the ordered list but includes the empty or null rows and is very slow for table with >10000 results. any suggestions?

```
SELECT id, 
  title, 
  pollid, 
  COUNT(pollid) AS clean_count 
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id, pollid 
  FROM tbl_votes
) AS tmp_tbl 
JOIN tbl_polls 
  ON tbl_polls.id = tmp_tbl.pollid 
WHERE not isnull(tmp_tbl.user_id) 
GROUP BY pollid 
ORDER BY clean_count DESC
```

Code to match results of votes with voters:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fbid, COALESCE(username, 'User not found.') 
AS username 
FROM tbl_votes JOIN tbl_users 
ON tbl_users.fbid = tbl_votes.user_id 
WHERE pollid = $band_id AND not isnull(username)
```

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the empty/null rows for the result set?

Comment: yes. or even better show them in separate field for comparison.

Comment: Modify your inner select? `SELECT DISTINCT user_id, pollid 
  FROM tbl_votes WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Tried that allready. the result should be equal to the sum of the list of users voted. I added the code for list of voters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, 
  title, 
  pollid, 
  COUNT(pollid) AS clean_count,
  group_concat(DISTINCT u.name) AS user
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id, pollid 
  FROM tbl_votes
) AS tmp_tbl 
JOIN tbl_polls 
  ON tbl_polls.id = tmp_tbl.pollid
JOIN tbl_users AS u 
ON tmp_tbl.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE not isnull(tmp_tbl.user_id) 
GROUP BY pollid 
ORDER BY clean_count DESC
```

This is the sample data that I used:

```
    CREATE TABLE tbl_polls (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(50)
  );


CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
  user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
  );

CREATE TABLE tbl_votes (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  pollid INT,
  user_id INT,
  INDEX (pollid,user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (pollid) REFERENCES tbl_polls(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tbl_users(user_id)
  );

INSERT INTO tbl_polls (title)
VALUES ('Title 1'),('Title 2'),('Title 3');


INSERT INTO tbl_users (name)
VALUES ('Bob'),('Jack'),('Joe'),('Tom');

INSERT INTO tbl_votes (pollid,user_id)
VALUES (1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,1),(2,4),(2,4),(3,1),(2,1),(1,4);
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ce07/38)

I have used group concat to get the names for your list. Furthermore, to speed up your database have you tried adding index to the foreign keys?

B.T.W. I don't understand your comment that some some votes lack pollid and user_id. If that is the case have a look at this.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Foreign keys are magic, though i had some problems implementing them since there are empty or null fields which answers your confusion with lacking fields i supose. Thanks again.

Comment: @Radical one more question, i simplified query by removing tbl_users as id is enough for now, my problem is group_concat limits set of result. how can i show all comma separated user_ids so that clean_count matches count of separated list?

Comment: @jozenovak I am a bit puzzled is this what you need http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ce07/53. If not could you explain your question by showing the results you need?

Comment: @Radical sory about the puzzles, here is the link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98ae8/1/0. Now lets say Title 1 has > 1000 votes... in my case group_concat would show only first cca 30 user_ids because of the group_concat limits. Is there a way to show them all?

Comment: @jozenovak group_concat does indeed have a limit. You can alter the limit by using `SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = type in a value;`. See SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445048/is-there-a-length-limit-to-group-concat-or-another-reason-why-it-would-not-work.  However at some point it will also truncate your output. You could try to create a temporal table. I have tried both action before, so I will need to read up on that to answer your question. A less complicate option will probably be to use php to split up the query.

Comment: since i have 15digit user_ids and a lot more votes to come, i will do it php wise. Ill mark your answer as correct. Tnx.

Comment: Hey, I wish I could solve your question with a query. If I can come up with something I will let you know. But for now I think that the best solution by far is to use PHP. Good luck with your project.